# Aggregation in Join and where

Tags: sql

I have this Query for Invertory Balance and work well:

```
Select A.BATCH_ID , 
       A.QTY_MOV - IsNull(B.QTY_USED,0) As BALANCE
From P_BATCH_PRODUC A
Left OUTER Join (Select MATERIAL_ID, 
                    BATCH_MATERIAL_ID), 
                    SUM(QTY_INS) QTY_USED 
                    From CONSUMPTION  
                    Group By MATERIAL_ID, BATCH_MATERIAL_ID) As B 
On B.MATERIAL_ID= A.PRODUCT_ID
   And A.BATCH_ID = B.BATCH_MATERIAL_ID"
Where A.QTY_MOV - IsNull(B.QTY_USED,0) > 0 
      AND  A.PRODUCT_ID= 1
      and A.BATCH_ID = 1
```

But now, it's possible to have more than one A.QTY_MOV for each A.BATCH_ID , so i need to Change A.QTY_MOV to Sum(A.QTY_MOV ). What do I need to change for that?
Sample:
Table A

```
+------------+------------+---------+
| Product_ID | Batch_ID   | Qty_Mov |
+------------+------------+---------+
|        1   |          1 | 100     |
|        1   |          1 | 150     |
|        2   |          1 |  80     |
|        1   |          3 | 100     |
|        1   |          4 | 100     |
+------------+------------+---------+
```

Table B

```
+------------------+------------+------------+----------+--+
| BATCH_MATERIAL_ID| Product_ID | Batch_ID   | Qty_USED |  |
+------------------+------------+------------+----------+--+
|          1       |        1   |          1 |       80 |  |
|          2       |        1   |          1 |       10 |  |
|          3       |        1   |          2 |      150 |  |
|          4       |        1   |          3 |       80 |  |
+------------------+------------+------------+----------+--+
```

This is what I want

```
Batch_ID   BALANCE
----------  --------------- 
1           160
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Works? Syntax error!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I put sample and desired results

Answer (score 0):

Based strictly on the question, it sounds like you want a window function:

```
Select A.BATCH_ID , 
       SUM(A.QTY_MOV) OVER (PARTITION BY A.BATCH_ID) - IsNull(B.QTY_USED,0) As BALANCE
```

I don't know if this does anything useful.  If it does not, you should ask a *new* question with sample data and an explanation of logic.